# Is it okay to say "you screw the nut on the bolt to secure the net in the panel"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is a plastic basketball net for little children to play

So, we have 3 things: the bolt which is a part of the net (ie, the bolt is sticking out from the net), the nut, and the panel with a hole as shown in the below picture

[image]

We put the bolt through the hole of the panel. On the other side of the panel, we screw the nut onto the bolt to secure the net in the panel.

Note: the panel is very thick, about 5 centimetre thick.

Is it okay to say "**you screw the nut on the bolt to secure the net in the panel**"?

I am not sure if we say "**to secure the net in / on / to the thick panel**" because the bolt and the net are a whole piece.

So, do we say "**to put the net in the panel**" as only the bolt part of the net goes into it?

Also, in [the dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/secure), they say "**to secure something to something**"

Comment: Your first sentence is fine, if you want to describe exactly how to do it. If you don't need to go into so much detail you could say something like _attach_ or _secure the net to the panel_.

Comment: The language is a bit technical and adult for a small child. I'd say 'you put the nut through the hole and do it up tight'.